# qt5.5 doesn't show system tray

Tags: c++, linux, qt, gnome-3, xfce

here is [similar problem](https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/201545695-After-upgrade-to-3-x-the-dropbox-tray-icon-is-missing-XFCE-Xubuntu-14-04-1-x64-), but I can't get answer from it.

I try [official example](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/tree/5.5/examples/widgets/desktop/systray) and see following screenshot(in shot, the qt app system tray doesn't exist)

[image]

How to make system tray show?

here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(systray)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(Qt5Widgets_DIR /home/roroco/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets)
set(Qt5Gui_DIR /home/roroco/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui)
find_package(Qt5Widgets)

add_executable(main main.cpp window.cpp systray.qrc)
target_link_libraries(main Qt5::Widgets)
```

my linux version(desktop environment is xfce)

```
roroco@roroco ~/Pictures $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela
Release:    17.2
Codename:   rafaela
```

Answer (score 0):

I get solution from [this](https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205672126-Release-Candidate-3-14-5?page=2#comments)

> Then under 'session & startup' I created a new autostart entry with
>   the following command:
>
> bash -c 'export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="" && dropbox start -i'

so the ugly solution is make sure DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS before you launch qt app, I hope someone can improve this answer and tell me its mechanism